# Downmix surround to Dolby Pro-Logic at the OS/driver level in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, audio, surround-sound, dolby-pro-logic

First off, I'm talking about [Dolby Pro-Logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolby_Pro-Logic#Dolby_Pro_Logic), a really old tech for encoding 4 audio channels (L/R/C/SR) into two analog outputs, and then extracting them again. It was used in surround sound systems in the last century.

I have a modern PC that can output 5.1 analog audio (Three outputs on the back carry six channels of audio). But I have a really old surround sound reciever that only has a two-channel, L/R input, which it extracts 4 channels of audio from, and outputs to 5.1 speakers.

What I want is some way for the OS, Windows 7, to act as if I really had 5.1 audio channels available, so applications produce surround audio, but before outputting it out of the back of my PC, apply Dolby Pro-Logic matrix encoding so that it outputs over only two channels. These two channels would then get sent to my receiver via a RCA cable, which would decode it again and drive the surround speakers.

Is anything like this possible? I'm pretty sure I could do it at an application / codec level, but I'm looking for something that I just have to set once.

Comment: I know it isn't exactly what you want, but have you tried the virtual surround enhancement?

Comment: For movies, you just need to check off "pass through" (somewhere) in the drivers and possibly the video player. I have yet to find a solution that works transparently for all software, and never found one for games. The real solution is a sound card which supports surround over spdif/rca. Some rare realtek HD built-in chipsets support this, but the mainboard mfg has to pay the license to enable it. They rarely do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Virtual Surround to encode for Dolby Pro Logic.

*Note that I am using an onboard Realtek ALC885 chipset and Microsoft drivers. I haven't tested this method with Realtek drivers.*

1. In Windows 7, open **Sound** in the Control Panel and click the **Playback** tab to configure your desired device for Dolby Pro Logic encoding.
2. Highlight the device and click the **Configure** button at the bottom of the pane.

   I'm using the analog output on my back IO panel which is called "Speakers" in my device list*
3. Ensure that **Stereo** is selected in the Audio Channels list and click **Next**.
4. Ensure that **Front left and right** is checked for the Full-range speakers option and click **Next**.

   Note that the **Surround speakers** option will be unavailable. This is because surround channels are going to be encoded by the Virtual Surround enhancement and then sent as a stereo stream.
5. Click **Finish** to close the Speaker Setup window.
6. With the device still selected in the Playback pane, click the **Properties** button.
7. Click the **Enhancements** tab and check **Virtual Surround**.

   Notice the Properties pane below the list which describes the enhancement in detail. The Status should read **Enabled**.
8. Click **OK** to save your changes and close the Properties window.
9. Click **OK** once more on the Sound window to close.

You should now be able to run your matrixed stereo stream from your computers analog stereo output to the analog stereo input on your Dolby Pro Logic receiver for L/C/R/SR audio.

I've noticed that because the Playback device is configured for stereo output, most programs will mix stereo by default. You have to configure the program to mix quad or 5.1 so that the VS enhancement can encode the matrixed stereo mix.

Answer (score 1):

Use KMPLAYER. In the input, choose "original", on the output, choose "DolbyPrologic". In the sound card, activate STEREO (which means, tell your PC that you only have two normal spekaers connecter to the main green output). Activate ProLogic in your decoder. Voila!
You don't have to encode the movies, just use Kmplayer to output the sound as a prologic sound. It works for me ;D

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do it using codecs. Though since Dolby Pro-Logic is a licensed format, I doubt you will find support for converting audio streams to it using open source codecs. You would have to go the paid route and might have to use a player such as Arcsoft TotalMedia Theatre or PowerDVD.

If your surround sound receiver supports a coax/optical S/PDIF, then you could use that. If your computer does not have the necessary connector, you can pickup a sound card (external or interal) that supports the format/connector and go that way.

Speaking of which, your best bet might be to get an external sound card that supports Dolby Pro-Logic matrix encoding.

Comment: I doubt you need a license, it's a very simple matrix encoding, from like 20+ years ago. It's right there in wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolby_Pro-Logic#Dolby_encoding_matrices . I've done it before with mplayer on linux, it could downmix 5.1 audio from DVD, or mkv files or whatever. It's likely what I want to do is not possible, but that's why I'm asking, because not sure if it is. Finally -- what about when I play video games? Obviously DVD player codecs wont solve the problem there, which is why I was looking for a lower level solution.

Comment: Then the only only possible route to cover games too would be to go a sound card that does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try FFDShow. It provides a number of options with regards to downmixing including Dolby Pro-Logic II.

http://mewiki.project357.com/wiki/FFDShow_reference#Mixer

Answer (score 0):

[**AC3Filter**](http://www.ac3filter.net/wiki/AC3Filter) (a decoder and processor filter) can allow downmixing to Dolby Surround/Pro Logic or Dolby Pro Logic II, if configured to do so. Your media player must also be configured to use AC3Filter.

Relevant features as quoted from its website:

> - Down-mix any audio track to any number of channels (to match your speaker configuration)
> - If you have an external Dolby ProLogic decoder, you may use ProLogic down-mix to help DPL decoder to extract surround information

[image: Screenshot of AC3Filter configured to output in Dolby Prologic II]