# finding a 5.1 to pro logic converter

Tags: audio, surround-sound, dolby-pro-logic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Downmix surround to Dolby Pro-Logic at the OS/driver level in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/242229/downmix-surround-to-dolby-pro-logic-at-the-os-driver-level-in-windows-7)

I was never very good when it came to the audio side of things, so maybe someone can help me here.

The way I understand it is, a Dolby Pro Logic system can take in audio that is compressed as Pro Logic data from a regular 2.5mm and then uncompress on the other end to create surround sound. is this true?

if so.

I have a samsung HT system which has Pro Logic as one of the options. What software can I use to convert my surround sound audio into the Pro Logic format, (codecs won't be enough, because I also want to be able to hear surround sound from my games)

Cheers, and thank's a tonne for any help or pointers.

Comment: I don't know enough about Dolby audio to post an answer, but you can't "uncompress" analog audio (which is what you get from a 2.5 or 3.5mm or 1/4" jack).

Comment: @user55325 You might want to read up on Dolby Pro Logic. It's an analog format that manages to downmix even as much as 9.1 surround (as of IIz) into a two channel (stereo) audio stream in a way that allows it to be re-expanded back to 9.1 surround using all sorts of analog black magic. It's not being "uncompressed" in the digital information-theory way you and I would think of it, but some word like "uncompressed" or "expanded" or "unpacked" or "decoded" still seems to apply.

Comment: That's what I thought too @Spiff , but it didn't work out of the box so I thought there must be some sort of software to downmix my surround sound from games/movies etc..

Comment: @Spiff, I can't ask any questions in the other thread, since I don't have any privileges, would you please answer me here, or unlock this thread?

Comment: @vvMINOvv What was wrong with the answers on the other thread? Did FFDShow or KMPlayer meet your needs? If they don't, then post a new Question referencing that other Question, and explaining what it is that you need to know that wasn't covered in the other Question.

Comment: thanks a tonne @Spiff I didn't think that was allowed hehe... (oh and no FFDShow etc.. didn't help) Cheers.